# How to get bundle label from entity

Tags: 8, entities

How do I get the human-readable label of a bundle from a loaded entity.

Lets say I want to get the label of a node of bundle *my_article* which is *"My awesome article"*

```
// Load a node
$node = Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load(4);

print $node->bundle(); // prints the machine-readable name. e.g. 'my_article'.

print $node->getEntityType()->getBundleLabel(); // prints 'content type'.
```

I am only able to get the machine-readable name of the bundle or the Label of entity ("content type", "taxonomy term", etc), but how do I get the Label of the bundle?

P.S. I would prefer it to not use deprecated classes/functions

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I can't see anything direct, loading the node type entity itself is an option though:

```
$bundle_label = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node_type')
  ->load($node->bundle())
  ->label();
```

Or as Berdir pointed out in the comments, there's a quicker way through the entity reference field:

```
$bundle_label = $node->type->entity->label();
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I would just use entityTypeManager instead of the deprecated entityManager.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realise it was deprecated. Fixed it up

Comment: It's not available as a method, but the type is an entity reference, so you can also just do this: $node->type->entity->label()

Comment: This is answering only the node type.. and not entities in general..

Comment: @ssibal Yep, as per the question. The bundle key will be different per entity type (but can also be retrieved from metadata)

Comment: Note: $term->type->entity->label() and $term->vocabulary->entity->label() don't work on taxonomy terms, I think you have to use the entity type manager to load the type to get the label.

Comment: @oknate For terms the bundle key is `vid`, so it'd be `$term->vid->entity->label()`

Comment: If you want to get this information about a block type you need to use the entity type "block_content_type" in the sample code above, not "block_content".

Answer (score 16):

Note that the accepted answer applies specifically to node entities but all entities have bundles. Many entities, like `user` or `menu_link_content` (for custom menu links), only have one bundle which corresponds to the entity type itself.

The `entity_type.bundle.info` service, implemented by [Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeBundleInfo](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityTypeBundleInfo.php/class/EntityTypeBundleInfo/8), provides access to entity bundle information. Its methods `getAllBundleInfo()` and `getBundleInfo($entity_type_id)` return an array keyed by entity type and bundle machine name respectively, with the former then containing an array of bundles keyed by bundle machine name. Each bundle has a `label` key with the translated bundle friendly name.

Below is an example that shows the difference between content entity machine names, labels, bundle machine names, and bundle labels. The code assumes that there is at least one custom menu link with an ID of `1`. It also assumes there is an `article` node type (bundle), that there is at least one node with an ID of `1`, and that the node is of the node type (bundle) `article`.

```php
<?php

$entity_type_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$bundle_info = \Drupal::service("entity_type.bundle.info")->getAllBundleInfo();

$current_user = \Drupal::currentUser()->getAccount();

// Prints "user".
print $current_user->getEntityTypeId() . PHP_EOL;

// Prints "User".
print $current_user->getEntityType()->getLabel() . PHP_EOL;

// Prints "user".
print $current_user->bundle() . PHP_EOL;

// Prints "User".
print $bundle_info[$current_user->getEntityTypeId()][$current_user->bundle()]['label'] . PHP_EOL;

$my_menu_link = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('menu_link_content')->load(1);

// Prints "menu_link_content".
print $my_menu_link->getEntityTypeId() . PHP_EOL;

// Prints "Custom menu link".
print $my_menu_link->getEntityType()->getLabel() . PHP_EOL;

// Prints "menu_link_content".
print $my_menu_link->bundle() . PHP_EOL;

// Prints "Custom menu link".
print $bundle_info[$my_menu_link->getEntityTypeId()][$my_menu_link->bundle()]['label'] . PHP_EOL;

$my_article = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('node')->load(1);

// Prints "node".
print $my_article->getEntityTypeId() . PHP_EOL;

// Prints "Content".
print $my_article->getEntityType()->getLabel() . PHP_EOL;

// Prints "article".
print $my_article->bundle() . PHP_EOL;

// Prints "Article".
print $bundle_info[$my_article->getEntityTypeId()][$my_article->bundle()]['label'] . PHP_EOL;
```

Be sure to use [dependency injection](https://www.drupal.org/node/2133171) where possible in your code rather than relying on the static methods of the `Drupal` class.

Comment: Very helpful to have an answer that works for all entity types. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

If you are not sure about the `$entity` type, it can be:

```
if ($entity->bundle()) {
  $bundle_type_id = $entity->getEntityType()->getBundleEntityType();
  $bundle_label = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage($bundle_type_id)
    ->load($entity->bundle())
    ->label();
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer: original question asking the "bundle label of entity" not the bundle label of a node..

Answer (score 6):

The following works as well:

```
$type = NodeType::load($node->bundle());
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions here worked for me. I finally used the `entity_type.bundle.info` service like this.

```
$entity_type = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
$entity_bundle = $entity->bundle();
$bundle_info = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getBundleInfo($entity_type);
$label = $bundle_info[$entity_bundle]['label'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient solution, but for sake of completeness, this works:

```
\Drupal::token()->replace('[node:type-name]', ['node' => $node]);
```

or

```
\Drupal::service('token')->replace('[node:type-name]', ['node' => $node]);
```