# Convert machine to human readable node type on page--node--add.html.twig (twig template variables)

Tags: 8, theming

I tried to create a variable on hook_preprocess_page to achieve it, but I'm only getting the machine readable name so far.

```
$variables['node_type'] = FALSE;
if ($current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath()) {
  $path_args = explode('/', $current_path);
  $node_type = $path_args[3];
  $variables['node_type'] = $node_type;
}
```

**UPDATED**

For some reason it works on node add form and node edit forms:

```
if ($current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath()) {
  $node_type = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node_type')->load($node->getType())->get('name');
  $variables['node_type'] = $node_type;
}
```

I just need update the condition because it I'm getting the error on `/node/add/` page  (without content type)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a `node` object in the `node.add` route, it doesn't exist there yet. But you can still get it from the `node_type` parameter. Untested, but following the code from [NodeController.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Controller%21NodeController.php/function/NodeController%3A%3AaddPage/8.7.x) you should be able to get the label with something like this:

```
//get the machine name from route
$machineName = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_type');
//get the label via definition
$nodeTypeLabel = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('node_type')->load($machineName)->label();
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is not clear but as I understand you want to pass the node type readable name to the template and this is the easiest way :

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables){
 //Get the current page rendered node(s).
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    // You can get any information about the
    // rendered node through the $node methods
    //just kint($node) then replace the label() method with another one.
    $variables['node_type'] = $node->label();
  }
}
```

Comment: this code returns node_type bool FALSE (page--node--add.html.twig)

Comment: I HAVE edited it and it work now, just I have forget to put the &variables in function argument.

Comment: @MarwenAmri this won't work as expected. The OP wants the node bundle label not the node instance label. Check https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/187983/57634. I've edited your answer with the proper code.